# How to obtain JBoss Server Group Name programatically when deployed to a domain

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, wildfly, jboss-eap-6

How can I obtain the jboss eap 6.x / wildfly server group name programmatically from within a java enterprise application deployed to a domain?

Some of the other jboss values such as node name can be obtained via system property values but server-group-name does not appear to be exposed this way.

I would like to be able to show the server group name (i.e. the cluster name) in a system diagnostics function for technical users to verify they are looking at the correct system...  (npe, dev, prod etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that I need to use JMX to obtain this value as its exposed via an MBean to the JVM (verifyable via JConsole....)

So answering my own question:

```
try {
    ObjectName serverMBean = new ObjectName("jboss.as:management-root=server");
    MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    String serverGroupName = (String) ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().getAttribute(serverMBean, "serverGroup");
    logger.info("JBoss server group name is" + serverGroupName);
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Unable to identify JBoss server-group-name", e);
}
```

If the application might also be deployed to a standalone server one could query the `launchType` attribute first. Valid values appear to be STANDALONE or DOMAIN.

In STANDALONE mode the `serverGroup` attribute is not available however one could use the `jboss.node.name` system property as an alternative system identifier.

Answer (score 1):

One other (and maybe better) way to do it is to use the management API https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Management+API+reference .

Comment: Thanks for the answer... are you provide or refer to some example java code?.  Remember this needs to be accessed from the deployed app inside the JEE server. I suspect it would require using management credentials from within the app to issue a http request to a local port (how does the app know which port?) and then parsing the resultant json.
Overall it does appear more complex than the JMX solution.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/The+native+management+API shows the code. It won't be more complicated than JMX (or are you exposing your whole server configuration without credentials on the default port ? ) and will provide more options. If you are in a webapp you can also use Javascript and JSON to access this API just like the webconsole does.

Comment: Looking at that API spec it appears primarily intended for execution from outside the container. 
If you can show a couple of lines of working java code that uses the API to capture the server-group-name and that will work from code deployed inside any JBoss container (regardless of whether as a EAR, EJB, WAR or JAR library) then I'll accept your answer.  Remember also the container is secure and I shouldn't need to expose external management credentials to the deployed application.